# Unity: How To Assign ScriptableObject Instance In Editor Code

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor, scriptable-object

Want to access ScriptableObject data from an editor code, namely a custom Node Graph Editor code:

1. Create a ScriptableObject containing Color field.
2. Create an instance of that SO and set the Color in the inspector.
3. Acquire that SO instance from an editor script.(if this was a Monobehavior we could drag drop into a SerializeField, how to achieve this from an editor script?)
4. Use the color from SO instance.

Comment: This might not even be possible, if it isn't can  someone comment and clarify so I can delete this question. Just trying to make my editor code more managable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

SO SOInstance = Resources.Load("PATH_OF_YOUR_SO");

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html